# Need two controllers for one route for my Ember app

Tags: ember.js

I building a simple page with an "edit event" form and a message thread on the bottom.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="stack">
  <div class='stack'>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12" style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;">

          {{#if isEditing}}
            {{partial 'stack/edit'}}
            <button {{action 'doneEditing'}}>Done</button>
          {{else}}
            <button {{action 'edit'}}>Edit</button>
          {{/if}}

        <h1>{{stack.title}}</h1>
        <h2>at {{stack.date}} <small class='muted'>({{format-date date}})</small></h2>

        <hr>

        <div class='intro'>
          {{stack.location}}
        </div>

        <div class='below-the-fold'>
          {{stack.details}}
        </div>


        <div class="chatbox jumbotron">
          <ul id="messageList">
            {{#each}}
              <li>{{username}} : {{stack.message}}</li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul>
        </div>
          <form {{action "sendMessage" on="submit"}}>
            <p>{{input type="text" placeholder="username" value=username disabled=entryNotAllowed size="15"}}
              {{input type="text" placeholder="where?" value=stack.message disabled=entryNotAllowed size="50"}}</p>
            <button class="btn" {{action "sendMessage"}}>Send</button>
          </form>
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

I need two different controllers (one for event edit, one for create message). I use ArrayController for event edit, and ObjectController for create message. How do I put these two under one route?

```
App.StackController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    isEditing: false,

    actions: {
        edit: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },

        doneEditing: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
        },
    } 
});




App.MessageController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({     
    init: function() {
        this.set('message', Ember.Object.create());
    },
    actions: {
        sendMessage: function() {
            var newMessage = this.store.createRecord('message', {
                username: this.get('username'),
                message: this.get('stack.message'),
            });

            newMessage.save();

            alert('newMessage' + " is submitted!");
        },
    } 
});
```

I tried to use FormComponent, but this.store.createRecord doesn't work inside components. Am I supposed to use View?

Comment: Use your routes model hook to create the message and then pass that to your form component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose additional controllers via the needs api.

See http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

```
App.StackController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    needs : ['message'],

    isEditing: false,

    actions: {
        edit: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },

        doneEditing: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
        },
    } 
});
```

In your action helper, you can then target this controller.

```
<button class="btn" {{action "sendMessage" target=controllers.message}}>Send</button>
```